# Django data grouping using annotate

Tags: python, django, api

i have these 2 models

```
class Car(TimeStampedModel):
   name = models.CharField(_('Car Name'), max_length=50)

   manager = models.ForeignKey(
     'cars.Manager',
      verbose_name=_('Car Manager'),
      related_name='cars',
      on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    def __str__(self):
      return self.name

class Manager(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=25)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Car Manager')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Car Managers')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

i also created this serializer

```
class CarManagerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Manager
        fields = '__all__'
```

and then on the view, i try to get number_of_managed_cars by each manager using this way

```
def get(self, request):
    cars_managers = Manager.objects.all().annotate(number_of_managed_cars=Count('cars'))
    serializer = CarManagerSerializer(cars_managers, many=True)
    serializer_data = serializer.data
    return Response(serializer_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

then i try to hit the endpoint:

```
{
 {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John Doe",
  }
}
```

there's no number_of_managed_cars on the result.

i followed this : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/
still cant get the results right.

where did i miss ?

Comment: Where is your `CarManagerSerializer` class?

Comment: i just added it @JPG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the **`number_of_managed_cars`** field in the serializer class

```
class CarManagerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    number_of_managed_cars = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Manager
        fields = '__all__'
```